# Why would Eigen be slower at computing same calculating using columns of Eigen::Matrix vs loose Eigen::Vectors?

Tags: c++, eigen

While trying to speed up a calculation, I was very confused to find out that it took more than twice as long to compute when loading my data into columns of a col-major Eigen::Matrix to do the calculation.  I would have expected that it would take nearly as much time as loading my data into individual Eigen::Vectors to do the calculation.  I am trying to understand what may be causing this slow down and would appreciate any help.  Would anyone happen to know what could be causing this?

My code look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Integer = int;
using Real = double;

using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<Real, Eigen::Dynamic, 6, Eigen::ColMajor>;

auto test0(const auto & rx_, const auto & rs_, const auto & x_, const auto & s_, const auto & p_, Real gamma_, auto & out_) -> Real
{
    out_.noalias() = (x_.cwiseProduct(rx_) - rs_).cwiseQuotient(x_.cwiseProduct(p_) + x_ * gamma_ + s_);
    return out_.sum();
}

auto test1(Matrix & mat_, Real gamma_) -> Real
{
    mat_.col(5).noalias() = (mat_.col(2).cwiseProduct(mat_.col(0)) - mat_.col(1)).cwiseQuotient(mat_.col(2).cwiseProduct(mat_.col(4)) + mat_.col(2) * gamma_ + mat_.col(3));
    return mat_.col(5).sum();
}

int main() {
    Integer size = 16384;
    Matrix mat{size, 6};
    Real gamma = 1e-6;

    mat.setRandom(size, 6);
    mat.col(2) = mat.col(2).cwiseAbs();
    mat.col(3) = mat.col(3).cwiseAbs();
    mat.col(4).setConstant(1e-6);

    Eigen::Vector<Real, Eigen::Dynamic> rx = mat.col(0);
    Eigen::Vector<Real, Eigen::Dynamic> rs = mat.col(1);
    Eigen::Vector<Real, Eigen::Dynamic> x = mat.col(2);
    Eigen::Vector<Real, Eigen::Dynamic> s = mat.col(3);
    Eigen::Vector<Real, Eigen::Dynamic> p = mat.col(4);
    Eigen::Vector<Real, Eigen::Dynamic> out = mat.col(5);

    out.setZero();

    test0(rx, rs, x, s, p, gamma, out);
    test0(rx, rs, x, s, p, gamma, out);
    test0(rx, rs, x, s, p, gamma, out);

    out.setZero();
    auto st1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto sum1 = test0(rx, rs, x, s, p, gamma, out);
    auto en1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    test1(mat, gamma);
    test1(mat, gamma);
    test1(mat, gamma);

    mat.col(5).setZero();
    auto st2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto sum2 = test1(mat, gamma);
    auto en2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << sum1 << " / " << sum2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(en1 - st1).count() << " / " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(en2 - st2).count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
-243842 / -243842
12708 / 25583
```

*EDIT: the issue seems to go away if I use

```
auto test1( Matrix & mat_, Real gamma_, auto & out_) -> Real
{
    out_.noalias() = (mat_.col(2).cwiseProduct(mat_.col(0)) - mat_.col(1)).cwiseQuotient(mat_.col(2).cwiseProduct(mat_.col(4)) + mat_.col(2) * gamma_ + mat_.col(3));
    return out_.sum();
}
```

Comment: Make sure you compile a release build with optimizations enabled. Then what I usually do is go hunt for answers myself. I run code using a profiler and lookup where the code is bottlenecking (and yes this includes looking at source code of libraries too).

Comment: I concur with Pepijn that you need to double-check your compiler settings. When I test it with GCC-13, both functions have similar performance. Compile with `-O3`

Comment: Some minor performance difference can be explained: For the column-access version, Eigen doesn't know at compile time that the start of each column is aligned to a 16 byte boundary. That limits the use of of SSE2 instructions (requires separate loads instead of using a memory operand in arithmetic instructions). If you compile with `-mavx` or better, that issue should go away

Comment: N.B.: If you only use element-wise operations, you should prefer the `Array` vs the `Matrix` class. E.g. You could write `arr_.col(5) = (arr_.col(2)*(arr_.col(0)) - arr_.col(1))/(arr_.col(2)*(arr_.col(4)) + arr_.col(2) * gamma_ + arr_.col(3));` instead of `mat_.col(5).noalias() = (mat_.col(2).cwiseProduct(mat_.col(0)) - mat_.col(1)).cwiseQuotient(mat_.col(2).cwiseProduct(mat_.col(4)) + mat_.col(2) * gamma_ + mat_.col(3));` (This only improves readability, but should not influence performance when compiled with optimizations)